# Как исправить ошибку типа в цикле перебора ключей объекта

Tags: javascript, typescript

Как исправить ошибку, которая внутри цикла у `b[obj]`? Спасибо

> Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.   Type
> 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

```
type C = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

const a: C = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'mom',
};

const b: C = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'dad',
};

(Object.keys(a) as (keyof C)[]).forEach((obj) => {
    b[obj] = a[obj];
});
```

Comment: Страдать и использовать any. Или не писать такой неоднозначный код.

Comment: достаточно выделить один тип для переменных `a` и `b` и использовать его.

Comment: In order to make it safe, TS tries to create common safe type for both `string` and `number`. It means that these two types are merged. `string & number` - gives you `never`. In order to fix it you can try `reduce`. You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67857960/how-to-selectively-assign-from-one-partial-to-another-in-typescript/67860407#67860407) for more explanation or my [article](https://catchts.com/mutations). In general, TS does not like when you mutate your values

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы помочь определиться с типом, нужно задать конкретный тип для `obj`, вместо объединения.

Для этого можно передавать `generic` функцию

```
(Object.keys(a) as (keyof typeof a)[]).forEach(<T extends keyof typeof a>(obj:T) => {
    b[obj] = a[obj];
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=13&ssc=4&pln=11&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gKBpmBLAJgLhgEYAaDLMOAWwFNCByKkK+sgXwG401RJYAjQlACeABxogAZvCSpymPIVLyYlWg1xxcrNJ24AKAPL8AVjWBQAdAGsawiPrgBKeBBj7bwqTBHjvzgG0AXSdLSRAAJwBROGAAC30AHgAVGBoADygaMFw3T29fCWk4AD59EFN8ZJdEErksGH4AipMg2Thm0yCuNicOIA)